# Lightswitch html client Unsaved changes on page

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I had a details screen which I changed to a browse screen. I implemented a save button which calls myapp.commitChanges();. I am facing an issue now where if I am on that details page and navigate away from the page to a new screen I get an pop up saying there are unsaved changes on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using this code below:

```
myapp.applyChanges();

setTimeout(function ({
  screen.tablenames.load() 
}, 100)
```

this code above will save all the changes currently on the screen, and then the setTimeout code refreshes the table view, this should prevent the screen saying that there is unsaved data...

if you require any more assistance please let me know, or a little more information like the table name will help

Comment: case msls.MessageBoxResult.yes:
                   screen.Job.StartTime = Date.now();
                       myapp.activeDataWorkspace.JMSData.GetJobStatusByDescription("Onsite Work in Progress").execute().then(function (result) {
                           screen.Job.Status = result.results[0];
                           myapp.commitChanges();
                       });
                   break;

Comment: I am commiting the change and the save is reflecting however if I go into that screen and navigate away itll ask to save changes

Comment: if you comment out the date, so the date isnt updated, then does it still ask for the changes to be saved? I had an issue with this myself... you could leave this as null for now... and try using myapp.applyChanges(); instead of myapp.commitChanges();

Comment: and are there any default values you are setting on that particular screen on creation? something like screen.tablename.thedate = new date(); this will change the value everytime the screen loads so use an if to determine if it is null or not..

Comment: ill give that a go by commenting out the date :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to resolve this trouble. That is hooking your javascript code to msls-2.5.3.js file, at line number 26303 and 13084. Insert a boolean variable into if condition and you can conduct Lightswitch to show confirmation dialog or not. This way is not regular but it's easy and safety.

Good luck.